# Dual simultaneous recording for both front and rear cameras

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, camera

We have been asked if the following requirement can be done on iOS (iPad).  It has been mentioned that it is not  possible on iOS.
- Need to have dual simultaneous recording/ capturing for both front and rear cameras.
- So if processor can take 50 frames per second for example,25 frames from front and 25 frames from back.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is possible. iOS only powers up one camera at a time. You won't be able to switch from one to the other quick enough to achieve that.